# Why isn't this reverse algorithm working?

Tags: c++, algorithm

```
#include <iostream>

void intswap ( int * pa, int * pb )
{
    int temp = *pa;
    *pa = *pb; 
    *pb = temp;
}

void reverse ( int * arr, size_t n )
{
    int * end = arr + n;
    while (arr != end && arr != --end) intswap(arr++,end);
}

int main ( )
{
    int myArray [] = {1, 69, 0, -123, 1377};
    size_t n = sizeof(myArray)/sizeof(int);
    reverse(myArray, sizeof(myArray, n));
    for ( size_t i = 0; i < n; ++i ) std::cout << myArray[i] << " ";

    return 0;
}
```

produces

```
-123 0 69 1 1377
```

What am I doing wrong? After all, it's the same algorithm as seen here: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/reverse/

Comment: `sizeof(myArray, n)`???

Comment: `sizeof(myArray, n)` is this C++? It won't compile in C.

Comment: Haha whoops. Type-o.

Comment: It sounds like you may need to learn how to use a debugger to step through your code. With a good debugger, you can execute your program line by line and see where it is deviating from what you expect. This is an essential tool if you are going to do any programming.  Further reading: **[How to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)**

Comment: @SouravGhosh It was a type-o, but it was working: http://codepad.org/SNm0unDF

Comment: [reverse(myArray, n);](http://codepad.org/shkMsyZQ)  works fine

Comment: sizeof is an operator, `,` is also a operator, so `sizeof(a, b)` is equal to `sizeof(b)` so `sizeof(size_t)` in your example (4 bytes probably)

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is that because of the comma operator `sizeof(myArray, n)` is exactly the same as `sizeof(n)` which is clearly in your case 4 bytes. You probably mean to just say `n` instead.

Answer (score -1):

Mark B has already pointed out the problem in your code. This is a suggestion to improve code readability. You can change `reverse` to:

```
void reverse ( int * arr, size_t n )
{
   int * end = arr + n;
   while ( arr < end )
   {
      --end;
      intswap(arr, end);
      ++arr;
   }
}
```

to make it more readable.

Comment: Apparently, my suggestion does not improve readability for some :) :)

Comment: Your answer is not related to the question and readability is subjective at some points. This is one of them